# How to get the values from one row of the page and provide same values in other page using selenium?

Tags: selenium

This is the question that I was asked in recent interview.Interviewer gave one scenario where we have to capture all information of any customer like his address,state,zip code that are present in first row and provide same values in fields present in another page.

Comment: We do not have enough information to answer your question. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

1.Open webpage 1
2.Read customer table data using helper method and store in array list
3.Open webpage 2
4.Supply data using array list to webpage fields 2

```
public class Cusomer {

    public WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "resources\\browserdrivers\\chromedriver.exe");

        // Launch Chrome
        DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(caps);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("Page 1 url which shows customer table");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

    @Test
    public void readCustomerDataFromPage1AndAddToPage2(){

    List<WebElement> customer =new ArrayList<WebElement>();//Creating arraylist.

    customer = getWebTableData();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("someXpath to go to next page")).click();
    // address,state,zip code

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath to address text box on next page")).sendKeys(customer.get(0).getText());
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath to state text box on next page")).sendKeys(customer.get(1)).getText());
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath to zipcode text box on next page")).sendKeys(customer.get(2).getText());

    }


    public List<WebElement> getWebTableData()  { 
        WebElement simpleTable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[2]")); 

        // Get all rows of table
        List<WebElement> rows = simpleTable.findElements(By.tagName("tr")); 

        // Get all td webelements for first row containing address,state,zip code
            List<WebElement> cols = rows.get(0).findElements(By.tagName("td")); 

            return cols;
        }


    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown(){
        if (driver != null)
            driver.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Everything seems right but inside sendkeys u should write customer.get(0).getText() or getAttribute(" ") because customer.get(0) will return web element

Comment: Thanks Amit... I tried the same logic and it worked.. I posted one another question related to Google page. Can you look into it?